# What is the id parameter passed in the uri with identity server

Tags: security, oauth, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I am using [oidc-token-manager](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-token-manager) with OAuth and [identity server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to setup authorization/authentication on my site. All the functionality is working fine . I am just wondering what the `id` parameter is that is being sent to identity server

`https://foobar.net/identity/ui/login?id=216257a45dbd3041eee88fa8aa5d3b0cidc`

and more specifically can i use that, in some form, to add a button on identity server to send the user back to the page that they came from. To be clear the post login redirect is working fine . once the user logs in with his/her credentials it automatically sends them back to the website. However there are 2 senarios that i want to take into account to extend the redirection.

**case 1** : If the user clicks login from the website and then is like *"nah dont really want to log in anymore have to afk and deal with some stuff just get me out of here will come back to it later"*

**case 2** : The user is not registered yet and clicks the login button from the website instead of the register button . On the login in page there is a "dont have an account? create one now" button. But in its current form it redirects to the registration with no way to set the same flow as the login where there is an automatic redirect back to the website, which will actually be a specific page that tells the user that he has registered and has a time period to check his email to authenticate himself to the site.

This is using an angular app with the set configuration for the OidcTokenManager as

```
 var config ={
            authorization_url:'https://foobar.net/identity/connect/authorize',                
            client_id:'foobar_id',
            redirect_uri:'http://localhost:5060/callback.html', // for testing
            response_type:'token token_id',
            scope:'fooscopes',
            authority:'https://foobar.net/identity',
            popup_redirect_uri:'http://localhost:5060/login-dialog.html',
            silent_renew: true
        };
```

Any help would be awesome . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` parameter that is passed to the login page is part of how IdentityServer manages the state for pending authorization requests. It's the id of the cookie that holds the `SignInMessage` that IdentityServer uses internally.

For case 2 if you click one of the additional links the `id` is passed along. It is then the responsibility of the custom page to get the user back to the login page with that id. I believe we have samples showing this.

Comment: Thank you .. the samples have helped a bunch , epic work you have done with this.